# How To Prepare for a Project Manager Role Technical Interview

Tags: interviewing, project-management

I will be having a technical interview for a pm role. What are the the points that I need to remember?

Comment: I think someone needs to talk to @neilfein about acceptable migration candidates.

Comment: @JimG. - Where would you suggest we sent it if not here?

Comment: @neilfein: Please read Jeff Atwood's guidance on migrating questions: http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/523/how-do-we-prevent-obviously-low-quality-questions-from-being-migrated-here/524#524

Answer (score 2):

> I will be having a technical interview for a pm role. What are the the
>   points that I need to remember?

You need to remember the points that will paint you in the best light in regards to the position at hand.

Go over the stated requirements for the position, particularly the technical requirements.

Recall the times in your employment history where you have had responsibility for that role, or similar roles. Pay close attention to how you handled those situations - both technically and process-wise. Be ready to say "Yes, I have dealt with X before. Here's how I tackled it." and give explicit steps you took.

Brush up on the relevant buzz-words. If there are any that you use, but don't have a deep understanding regarding their meaning, now is the time to refresh yourself. When I conduct a technical interview, I always dig in to see if candidates truly understand what the keywords on their resume mean.

Good luck!